# Change actual text (easily?) based on screen width?

Tags: css, responsive-design, viewport

I'm setting up an off-the-shelf shopping cart with a responsive design template.  I have a section that is horizontally oriented with larger viewports and vertically oriented with smaller devices.  I *want* to use copy that says "see to the right for [whatever]"... but on a smaller device, it isn't "to the right" but rather underneath.  So I'd like to make it dynamically say "see below" when the viewport changes.

Possible?  And simple?  I don't want a mess of code that myself or other furture admin are going to have to adjust if they want to reword it.  But if it can be done with a simple  or whatever with all the code contained in css then that's fine.

Otherwise I'll accept "no" if that's the better answer.

Comment: depends there are many ways of doing this, how much backwards compatibility are you looking for?

Comment: pure css - if you insert the text with the `content` property in css and then use media queries to hide the one that says 'right' and show the one that says below.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can do this using media query and the following approach.

Declare two spans having the desired data, one for large screens and other for smaller ones:

```
<span class="lg-view">See to the right</span>
<span class="sm-view">See below</span>
```

In css, display the `lg-view` span by default and hide the other one:

```
.lg-view{
   display:inline-block;
}

.sm-view{
   display:none;
}
```

Then inside `media query`, reverse the above styles:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .lg-view{
       display:none;
    }

    .sm-view{
       display:inline-block;
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect.  Works great.  Way simpler than I imagined!

Answer (score 4):

One way would be to use pseudo elements and media queries.  You could do something like this:

HTML:

```
<div><!-- empty by design --></div>
```

CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  div:before {
    content: "see below for [whatever]";
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 301px) {
  div:before {
    content: "see to the right for [whatever]";
  }
}
```

Obviously this is just a bare bones markup, but with a bit of tweaking it should do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

On Bootstrap 4, you could use the display property to easily manage this without writing media queries.

Sample below:

```
<div class="d-lg-none">hide on screens wider than lg</div>
<div class="d-none d-lg-block">hide on screens smaller than lg</div>
```

More information here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/